# create an on-click event for inserting sql statement to mysql-server by using javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql, webserver

I created a js file which can run in the console. However, I cannot perform the same function when I put them inside a function quote, e.g. (var function = function() {...} ).

How can I modify my code in order to achieve my goal? Simply click the button and insert the sql into the connected database.

Here is my original code:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "account",
  password: "password",
  database: "test"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");

    con.query("SELECT id FROM `task` order by id desc limit 1", function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result[0].id);
    var gid = result[0].id + 1;
    console.log(gid);

    var sql = "INSERT INTO `task` (`id`, `date`, `time`, `username`, `action`, `target`) VALUES ('"+gid+"', CURRENT_DATE(), CURRENT_TIME(), 'mum', 'hit', 'me')";
    con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("1 record inserted");
    alert("1 record inserted"); //no alert shown
    });
    });
});
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying  to create a click event, it can be done as below

```
$("#submit").on('click',function(){
   //call function to insert the data       
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Is it possible to have a plain javascript answer? I tried to use "var mum = function() {...}" to quote my code. When I tried to add "alert("1")" in the beginning of the code, it shows in my webpage but the code I posted did not work; therefore, there is no any sql inserted into my mysql database. Any solution?